# Is there a way to form reliably a Shapely Linestring from unordered list of points?

Tags: python, geometry, shapely

I have a list of points (1 list for x values 1 list for y values) from which I want to form a shapely Linestring, to later form a polygon out of, with Linestring.buffer. In 99% of the cases my linestrings are properly formed, but in some instances it fails to connect the segments from which my original x and y coordinates are made of. Instead it connects other consecutive segments to each oter. Would it be mandatory to use Multilinestrings? I would like to avoid this approach since I have another source of points where my approach works perfectly.
My code snippet:

```
line = np.vstack((x_values, y_values)).T
line=shgeo.LineString(line)
surrounding_polygon = line.buffer(width, cap_style=2)  
return surrounding_polygon
..
```

I have even tried to make sure that the segments overlap with each other, but it didn't help my case. On the image presented below, on the top it should be only the main "circular shape" should be present not the 2 additional crossing lines in the shape. [Shape in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBNMM.png)